# php super globals, how to use them

Tags: php, superglobals

small question, is it better to do

```
$HOST = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
```

and use `$HOST` throughout my web application

OR

is it better to do

```
define ( "HOST", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] );
```

and use `HOST` throughout my entire web application

OR

is it better to forget using variables and constants and just use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];` every time I need the host?

Which ways more efficient.
Which ways more readable.

Which way should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Its better for you use second one,

```
define ( "HOST", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] );
```

define it and use it anywhere..

Don't go for third one at any case, because hard coding will affect a lot in future.

Comment: This saves 17*n characters at the expense of readability and (a little) flexibility. No down vote as it was OPs suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The less global variables you have the better, IMHO so just use  `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` in all of your application. If you really want to define it

```
define ( "HOST", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] );
```

is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Global state is normally bad, since it couples components, breaking the [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) concept.

I would use [dependency injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163739.aspx) to pass parameters between classes and modules.

But if you really want to use a global variable, why don't you just use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]`?

Comment: Why the upvote? How does the contradictory buzzword advise answer OPs specific question?

Comment: Well, I always try to answer questions in the best possible way (from my point of view). In this case, I believe AlexMorley-Finch asks the wrong question, so I suggested a better approach to what he wants to achieve.

Comment: That's helpful. But if you don't actually intent to answer the question but suggest something entirely different, do so using comments. This is a non-answer, in particular because you close it with a question.

Comment: It is not entirely different. I just consider it one of the ways to solve the problem which AlexMorley-Finch just did not mention in his question.

Comment: Well, you could always add a concrete example of how carrying around values per DI is going to simplify OPs code (of which we know little). Not saying it's farfetched, merely a bit abstract.

Comment: Well, maybe you are right and it would be better off as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Better is a relative term. Using $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] is perfectly acceptable, since everyone looking at it instinctively knows what it's supposed to be and not have to guess if that contains a complete URL or otherwise.

Even if you have to spoof a production hostname for testing, you can still do so with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'www.mywebsite.whatever'`;